# How to add multiple facet field with angular $http

Tags: angularjs, solr

All:

Currently I use angular $http service to post SOLR search request.

```
        $http(
                {
                    method: 'JSONP',
                    url: $scope.SERVER, // here is solr core root
                    params:{
                        'json.wrf': 'JSON_CALLBACK',
                        'q': $scope.qs, // $scope.qs is just search keyword
                        'wt': 'json',
                        'indent':true,
                        'hl':'true',
                        'hl.fl':'content',
                        'hl.simple.pre':'<blk>',
                        'hl.simple.post':'</blk>',
                        'hl.snippets':'6',
                        'facet':'true',
                        // here I want to add multi facet field
                    }
                }
            )
            .success(function(result){
                // success handling.
            });
```

But when I add facet field, the final URL only accept the last one(must be overrode by last), I wonder if anyone could help with this.

Thanks

Comment: what is is angular version?

Comment: @sidgate right now I am using 1.2.16, but it is not required, I can change to other version as long as this can be solved

Comment: can you check whether you still face the issue with latest AngularJS?

Comment: @sidgate no, even with angular 1.3.5, the facet.field still the last field specified only.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:
Only add an array for "facet.field" with the facets names

```
params:{
                        'json.wrf': 'JSON_CALLBACK',
                        'q': $scope.qs, // $scope.qs is just search keyword
                        'wt': 'json',
                        'indent':true,
                        'hl':'true',
                        'hl.fl':'content',
                        'hl.simple.pre':'<blk>',
                        'hl.simple.post':'</blk>',
                        'hl.snippets':'6',
                        'facet': true,
                        'facet.field' : ['facet1', 'facet2', 'facet3']

}
```

Comment: Add an array for "facet.field"  with the facets names